# How to center an image horizontically and vertically in empty UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I want to present an empty state to the user if the table view is empty.
I have an image that i want to center horizontical and vertical inside the UIView.
However the position i get with my code is not completly right as it is a bit too much down.

What i tried so far:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

I also tried adding height and width constraints but it did not change anything.

How it looks: [UITableView with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvEk8.png)

SOLUTION:

```
let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: add Constraints on image as  Horizontally in Container and Vertically in container  and set Value 0.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Are you sure you don't tweak those constraints somehow after that?